# Unable to upload files to the server due to permissions

Tags: php, apache2

I am trying to upload a file from an Android app to a Ubuntu web server with PHP 7.4.12 using this PHP script to get the uploaded file and save it into a server folder:

```
<?php
  
    $file_path = "postsmedia/";
   

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Here you have the error log:

```
[Fri Nov 27 12:28:56.214230 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 29552] [client 172.31.39.159:64102] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(postsmedia/1606480134886.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/administrar/application/admin/subir_media_post.php on line 7
[Fri Nov 27 12:28:56.214258 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 29552] [client 172.31.39.159:64102] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpCV1Y9Z' to 'postsmedia/1606480134886.png' in /var/www/html/administrar/application/admin/subir_media_post.php on line 7
```

I can upload files directly to the server folder using FTP, but I guess the issue is a matter of permissions.

These are the permissions given to the server:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:ubuntu /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

I have also changed php.ini to allow greater files sizes to upload_max_size = 20M

What should I take into account to avoid the issue?

Comment: @Tyralcori, thanks, let me check

Comment: @Tyralcori, not the given answer but another answer has given me the tip. Thanks